# Setting multiple properties at once in Powershell

Tags: syntax, powershell

Is there a shorter way to set multiple properties to the same value in Powershell in one command than this?

Example:

```
(gi  "c:\test.txt").LastWriteTime = (gi  "c:\test.txt").LastAccessTime = (gi  "c:\test.txt").CreationTime = Get-date
```

I'm just curious if there is a way to shorten this syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```powershell
"CreationTime","LastWriteTime","LastAccessTime" |% {(gi test.txt).$_ = (get-date)}
```

Comment: Just for fun, you can also do this:  `$test.CreationTime, $test.LastWriteTime, $test.LastAccessTime = @(get-date) * 3`

Comment: Both your answers are not quite the same, semantically, as the op's example. The OP is guaranteed the same date on all three props. In your cases, not so. There's a chance of a roll over in both the foreach-object and the * multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a slightly modified version of Mjolinor's answer to solve a problem I had of incorrect date on files that had just been downloaded from a remote source.  I modified the code to make it cleaner to understand in case I have to come back to in the future (changed the short hand to full command names).

```powershell
# Correct Access/Create/Write times on transferred files
ForEach( $File in $TransferList ) {
    @("CreationTime","LastAccessTime","LastWriteTime") | ForEach {
        $(Get-Item $File.Name).$_ = $File.Date
    }
}
```